# Symfony using Mac OS X

Tags: symfony

I am trying to start a project using Symfony on a Mac Sierra.

I installed  Symfony successfully, but I get this warning:

> We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone
>   to select your timezone. in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/src/Symfony/Installer/NewCommand.php on
>   line 283  ✕  Symfony 3.2.1 was successfully installed but your system
>   doesn't meet its
>        technical requirements! Fix the following issues before executing
>        your Symfony application:  * date.timezone setting must be set
>      > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).

I tried to change php.ini with brackets editor on the created project on folders:

- project/vendor/doctrine/cache/test/travis/php.ini
- project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle/test/travis/php.ini

Didn't help.

As I read Symfony has built-in Apache Server.

Answer (score 2):

Those `php.ini` files are totally unrelated to what you have to do.

Open up the Terminal and type `php -i | grep "php.ini"`. That should reveal the location of the `php.ini` which is used by PHP in console mode.

`XAMPP` is known for using different `php.ini` file for the server. In order to find the the one used by the `XAMPP`, run a sample php file with `phpinfo()` from browser.

Also, note that `Symonfy` itself does not have the built-in server. In merely used the one `PHP` provided from version 5.4 and on.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I am Mac user, so , in Finder you need to go to  /private/etc, find php.ini.default,
Yo need to copy that file to the desktop. To edit you need to unlock the document. Just click Unlock if asked. Rename to  php.ini, set the date.timezone=Europe/YourCountry and do not forget to erase the semicolon before.And finally save it and put it back to etc.
Watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wb6Fh-B3W-o